# Creating a custom taxonomy terms + nodes menu in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, menu

I have a site using taxonomy terms and parent/child nodes using node hierarchy module. The content structure looks something like this:

-term1

---parent node1

-----child node1

-----child node2

---parent node2

-----child node3

-----child node4

-term2

---parent node3

-----child node5

-----child node6

...and so on. I need to create a custom drop-down menu that gets taxonomy terms and its associated parent nodes. I have very little programming and drupal experience and I don´t know whether I could use a combination of modules for this, or write sql queries in the template.php file. Could anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll want to use the Views module for this. It takes a little bit of getting your head around but the documentation is very good.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but views are either of type node or terms, I can't output both (terms and nested nodes) at same time, can I?

Comment: If you choose 'node', you can have the term as a field in the 'fields' section. Not certin it'll do what you're after though, I'm afraid. I'm pretty new to Drupal myself, just seemed like a job Views could do.

Comment: It won't do it, it shows repeteadly the terms for each node. Views don't seem to be the right approach, thanks for your help though. I suppose I'll have to right php+sql, but I don't know where and how...

Answer (score 0):

Duder, you just need [Taxonomy Menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu)!

For a drop down just add in [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus), [GigaMenu](http://drupal.org/project/gigamenu) or maybe [DHTML Menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu).

I've used all of these on multiple projects.

Comment: I have also used taxonomy menu, it will show the terms but how do I also show for each of those terms its nodes in the same menu?

Comment: Ahh sorry. If you want to avoid coding you could probably pull this off with a taxonomy node and then taxonomy menu with these: http://drupal.org/project/nat or http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_node. If you want to build a bit perhaps try http://drupal.org/project/menu_node

Answer (score 0):

If you are working for Drupal7. This module will provide what you want -- [Taxonomy field menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_field_menu)